# Home screen widget does not show up in android

Tags: android, android-appwidget

In my application, I have a `Fragment` which is attached to the main `activity`. This `Fragment` displays data with the help of an `adapter`. In the `adapter`, I have inflated a `layout` which has a `clickable text` "Watch From Home". The `adapter` displays data from the server. I want to show the same data on the home screen and when I click on the "Watch From Home" text, a home screen `widget` should be created without any user interaction.

I made a `receiver` `MyWidgetProvider`.What should the method `onClickText()` for "Watch From Home" have so that it takes me to the widget? I must admit, I am new to android. Thanks

Android Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pack.android.receiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

MyWidgetProvider.Java file

```
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private TextView team1Name;
    private TextView team2Name;
    private TextView team1Score;
    private TextView team2Score;

    public static boolean widgetView=false;
      private static final String LOG = "com.playup.android.receiver";

      public MyWidgetProvider(TextView team1Name, TextView team2Name, TextView team1Score, TextView team2Score){
          this.team1Name=team1Name;
          this.team2Name=team2Name;
          this.team1Score=team1Score;
          this.team2Score=team2Score;
          initializeViews();
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds) {

        Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");
        // Get all ids
        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

        // Build the intent to call the service
        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), UpdateWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

        // Update the widgets via the service
        context.startService(intent);
      }

      public void initializeViews(){
    //    team1Name= (TextView)content_layout.findViewById(R.id.team1Name);

      }
}
```

UpdateWidgetService

```
public class UpdateWidgetService extends Service {
  private static final String LOG = "com.playup.android.receiver";

  @Override
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    Log.i(LOG, "Called");
    // Create some random data

    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this
        .getApplicationContext());

    int[] allWidgetIds = intent
        .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
        MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds2 = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    Log.w(LOG, "From Intent" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds.length));
    Log.w(LOG, "Direct" + String.valueOf(allWidgetIds2.length));

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
      // Create some random data
      int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
          .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),0x7f030061);        //Since R could not be resolve, I used the generated ids
      Log.w("Widget", String.valueOf(number));
      // Set the text
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(0x7f0a022a,"Random: " + String.valueOf(number));

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),MyWidgetProvider.class);

      clickIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      clickIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,
          allWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(0x7f0a022a, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
    stopSelf();

    super.onStart(intent, startId);
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply saying, You can't create a home widget without any user interaction.

---

Update:

Your receiver tag should start like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyWidgetProvider" 
    android:label="My widget label" >
    <!-- The rest as is -->

</receiver>
```

Comment: okay, let's say we have user interaction. When I run my app, my widget doesn't get listed in the widgets on the desktop. How to bring the widget available there. please help.

Comment: Did you [declare your app widget in the manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Manifest)?

Comment: You mean by `doesn't get listed on the desktop` that it didn't show in the phone's widget list?

Answer (score 1):

Home Screen Widget can only add to Home Screen directly by user.Only user can add widget as guest to Home Screen or other applications.

**Edit:**

To see your widget in widgets list:

1. It is necessary that register your `AppWidgetProvider` in manifest.
2. Your App has to have **`Launcher/Main` Activity**,and App must be directly run by user,before it be visible in widgets list.This is necessary ,because no `broadcastreceiver`(and so no AppWidgetProvider),no `service`,... of your App could not register before your App run directly by user.If you look at your manifest,you will see that your App has no **`Launcher/Main` Activity**(it has only a receiver),so it can not run by user and your AppWidgetProvider(that is a broadcastreceiver) will not register and thereupon you can not see your widget in widget list.

Comment: the app has the following two requirements

Comment: @Feona what is Android API level that you try?Can you add your manifest and your AppWidgetProvider to question?

Answer (score 0):

This had me scratching my head for a while.
I had the `meta-data` tag as child of the `intent-filter` tag, which is wrong. The `meta-data` is to be child of the `receiver` tag.

Incorrect version

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".AppWidgetReceiver"
            android:label="AppWidgetReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                    android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Following is the correct version

```
<receiver android:name=".AppWidgetReceiver"
            android:label="AppWidgetReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/appwidget_info" />
        </receiver>
```